# excel files in sharepoint - referencing

Tags: excel, sharepoint-2007, excel-2003

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358268/referencing-or-copying-values-from-a-closed-excel-workbook-on-sharepoint-to-anot) and it seemed similar to my problem but I think that they are distinct enough to ask my question seperately. (I am happy to be wrong).

I have 2 excel spreadsheets. Spreadsheet 1 is a common spreadsheet to a few departments in my office so cannot be modified but I wish to use some of the data contained within to run spreadsheet 2. I am trying to do this organically within excel.

When I initially built spreadsheet 2 I had an 'offline' copy of spreadsheet 1 sat in my user folder so that I could test and debug quickly. Now that I come to try to use the 'online' version, I can initially set up the references fine. When I close spreadsheet 2 and reopen it I get asked if I would like to update the references as normal, but now it throws an error, it cant find the document in sharepoint.

I figure that my problem is this - when I initially reference the cells, the reference is pointing to some temp location that is produced when I had spreadsheet 1 open. So as soon as I close that spreadsheet the links are broken. Does this sound like a feasible explanation for what is happening?

If that is the case: How do I get the reference to point at a cell within spreadsheet 1 located on sharepoint?

Cheers for the help